# n doesn't change node.js version

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I have 12.19.0 and 14.15.4 on ubuntu. I can't use the n command to change active node version. Either the below does not work:

```
# which node
/root/node-12.19.0/bin/node
# n stable
   installed : v14.15.4 to /usr/local/bin/node
      active : v12.19.0 at /root/node-12.19.0/bin/node
# n 14.15.4
   installed : v14.15.4 to /usr/local/bin/node
      active : v12.19.0 at /root/node-12.19.0/bin/node
# echo $N_PREFIX/bin
/bin
```

How can I change the active version of node.js with n? Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you do run those commands — any errors? And do you have another version of Node installed somewhere? You can check by running `which node` — if that's path is different from `echo $N_PREFIX/bin`, that would be your issue.

Comment: @ZacAnger Thank you. I added the complete commands I issued. Yes, the path of node 
 is different. How can I fix it?

Comment: Does it switch to the right active version if you open a new terminal? Looks like you have two versions installed and also you don't have N_PREFIX set (since that showed just `/bin`, and `N_PREFIX` would point to one directory above the `/bin` level). To fix it, I would take a look at your `PATH` wherever you have that set (probably something like your .bashrc or .profile), figure out how you ended up with an install at /root/node-12.19.0 and get rid of that one, and then you should be good. The default for N_PREFIX is /usr/local so that's fine.

Comment: Thank you very much @ZacAnger. Yes, I set /root/node-12.19.0 in .zshrc. Now removed it and everything is good.

Comment: I'll copy-paste that to an answer, then.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have two versions installed and also you don't have N_PREFIX set (since that showed just /bin, and N_PREFIX would point to one directory above the /bin level). To fix it, I would take a look at your PATH wherever you have that set (probably something like your .bashrc or .profile), figure out how you ended up with an install at /root/node-12.19.0 and get rid of that one, and then you should be good. The default for N_PREFIX is /usr/local so that's fine.